# cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jms:listener-container'

Tags: spring

I am getting following error while deploying my application to glassfish 3.1 server,

**Exception while loading the app :**

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jms:listener-container'..
>   Please see server.log for more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Your question is a pain to read. When you want to get help, make some efforts to make yourself understood.
2. Your `applicationContexnt.xml` file probably miss JMS namespace declaration (see [Spring JMS documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/jms.html#jms-namespace)).

From Spring documentation, your XML file header needs to be at least (pay attention to JMS part) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd">

<!-- <bean/> definitions here -->

</beans>
```

You may have others namespace declarations such as `aop`, `util`, `context`, etc.